# What should you do when you see a posting on Careers and you know the employer is blatantly lying?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, jobs, advertising, employers

What should you do if you see a posting on Careers and you know the employer is blatantly lying about their organization?

Comment: You apply.  Only suckers are honest on their careers pages.

Answer (score 12):

There is a “flag a problem” link in the right-hand column of the job listing page (if you are logged in). Alternatively, you can always email careers@stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 5):

That seems like something you'd bring up with the team directly, if only so SO Careers can protect its own reputation. There's nothing the Meta community can do besides gawk, and typical site moderator powers won't be of any help, either.

Comment: However, sometimes gawking is fun.

Comment: Our latest Accu-Weather models are showing an 80% chance of fun and a 0% chance of constructive discussion. Back to you in the newsroom, @GeorgeStocker.

Comment: Best to keep the reporting private. Then it's up to the SE team to decide who is right, without having to hang out anyone's dirty laundry.... and without people risking lawsuits for libel/slander.

Comment: @PopularDemand Epic. Would watch again.